# How to filter SPARQL query with Java variables

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web

I have quiz game in which user have to answer questions like: What is German capital city name? Options are: Berlin Madrid London The data are in my owl file.

I have another ontology also in which I have rdfs:comment of resources (options of quiz questions) like rdfs:comment of Berlin, London etc. I want if user choose the wrong option i-e London, rdfs:comment of right option should be displayed to user, Berlin in this case.

```
  The right (correct) option I have is in java variable 'correct' and if user click wrong option, I want to show the rdfs:comment of correct option as:

        "SELECT  * " +
                    " WHERE {   ?x rdfs:comment ?y   "  +  "FILTER regex( ?x ,'"+correct+"' ) " +

              "}";
        System.out.println(queryString);
                     Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
            QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model) ;
            ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect() ;
                while (results.hasNext())
            {
                QuerySolution binding = results.nextSolution();

                        Literal l=binding.getLiteral("y");
                        String s=l.toString();

        The problem is that it does not show me the filtered value rdfs:comment. When I remove Filter, it shows all rdfs:comment of resources but with Filter value, it simply does not work.

        When I print the query, it shows the options values but does not display the rdfs:comment of that resources. 

         PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> prefix dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/page/>PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> SELECT  *  WHERE {   ?x rdfs:comment ?y   FILTER regex( ?x ,"Berlin" ) }

        PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> prefix dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/page/>PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> SELECT  *  WHERE {   ?x rdfs:comment ?y   FILTER regex( ?x ,"Rome" ) }

    My owl for rdfs:comment is like: Berlin--> rdfs:comment
    Rome--> rdfs:comment etc
```

Comment: How many students in your university are doing the same exercise/project? I'm pretty sure that you already asked on the Jena mailing list by somebody of your class.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your datastructure but I assume that the x's are URIs

For the filter to work you should do it like this:

FILTER regex( **str(?x)** ,"Berlin" )

Comment: I need to use variable name instead of constant Berlin, because next time when user clicks Next button, variable will contain Rome, Madrid etc and not always Berlin. I did not use the keyword str here, is it mandatory?

Comment: @s.shah `STR` is a SPARQL function that converts a IRI to a string and REGEX works on strings -  please always use the SPARQLl specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str

Comment: Sure you can also use FILTER regex( str(?x) ,' "+ correct +" ' )